# Set transition to start in motion layout after transitionCompleted

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a motion layout with left drag, When the transition is completed I want it to go back to the start state automatically. I tried the transitionListener, onTransitionCompleted function to set the motion layout to start but it's not working.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val ml = findViewById<MotionLayout>(R.id.motionLayout)
    val customListener = object : MotionLayout.TransitionListener {
        override fun onTransitionStarted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onTransitionChange(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Float) {
            if(p0?.progress == 1f){
                p0.transitionToStart()
            }
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            
                p0.transitionToStart()
            
        }

        override fun onTransitionTrigger(p0: MotionLayout?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean, p3: Float) {

        }

    }

    ml.setTransitionListener(customListener)
}
```

App:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the transition you can set

```
  <Transition
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    motion:autoTransition="animateToStart"
    motion:duration="1000">
```

This will automatically transition to the start when it reaches the end
If you are using an OnSwipe 2.1
has
<OnSwipe ...
motion:onTouchUp="neverCompleteToEnd" />